# como hacer para que se obtengan mas rapido los datos?

Tags: sql-server

Buen dia.

Tengo el siguiente Query el cual para obtener los datos que se requieren dura 25 minutos y quiero saber si hay alguna manera de hacerlo que dure menos en obtener los datos.

El Query es:

```
 SELECT   max(b.DateBonePile) Dates
                           FROM            STRGD12.SSS.[dbo].UdtBonepileTrend b
                           WHERE          b.Project = 'LUCENT FAD' and b.DateBonePile >= getdate() - 90
                           GROUP BY cast(b.DateBonePile AS date)
```

Cuando no filtro por el proyecto, query dura 7 segundos, pero cuando se filtra el proyecto es cuando dura 25 minutos.

Los campos de la tabla son los siguientes:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UdtBonepileTrend](
[Site] [varchar](9) NOT NULL,
[Project] [char](15) NOT NULL,
[ProductionOrderNumber] [char](20) NOT NULL,
[PartNumber] [char](37) NOT NULL,
[RevisionNbr] [char](20) NOT NULL,
[SerialNumber] [char](25) NOT NULL,
[CreationTime] [datetime] NULL,
[CreationAging] [int] NULL,
[FirstScanTime] [datetime] NULL,
[FirstScanAging] [int] NULL,
[FirstScanStation] [varchar](14) NOT NULL,
[Last Station/Work Center] [char](10) NOT NULL,
[Unit State] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
[Unit Status] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[Last Update] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Last Update Aging] [int] NULL,
[Total Visit Repair] [int] NULL,
[Looper Count] [int] NULL,
[Last Looper Count Date] [datetime] NULL,
[Last Looper Count Aging] [int] NULL,
[PeriodLastUpdate] [varchar](36) NULL,
[WipDaysException] [int] NULL,
[ExceptionDescription] [varchar](500) NULL,
[sysWCID] [int] NOT NULL,
[LastFail] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[LastFailAging] [int] NOT NULL,
[Flag] [varchar](76) NOT NULL,
[PassDate] [datetime] NULL,
[FailDate] [datetime] NULL,
[isPass] [int] NOT NULL,
[BonePileCriteria] [varchar](44) NULL,
[ContainerID] [dbo].[BarCode_type] NULL,
[Parent Serial Number] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
[Parent Status] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
[CreationTime_format] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[Last Update_format] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[FirstScanTime_format] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[Last Looper Count Date Format] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[StandardCost] [float] NULL,
[period] [int] NULL,
[strike] [int] NULL,
[DateBonePile] [datetime] NULL,
[ReportType] [varchar](8) NOT NULL
)
```

Los datos que contiene la tabla son los siguientes:

[image: Datos de la tabla]

El sql que utilizo es:

[image: Version SQL]

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Para ayudarte sería necesario que colocaras la estructura de las tablas, si poseen índices o no, el motor de base de datos y su versión (creo que es SQL Server, pero no estoy seguro) y toda la información que pueda resultar útil para quien lea la pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: @JosueArriola Ya edite la pregunta. con informacion extra .

Comment: Fundamental también ver los índices que tienes en esta tabla. Hay algo raro en tu consulta, estas agrupando por una columna que es la misma que usas en la función de agregación, eso está bien?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho si. lo que se pasa es que en esta tabla hay muchisimas unidades con diferente SerialNumber y pueden tener el mismo DateBonePile. entonces estoy agrupando solo para obtener el data time maximo de cada dia. pero al filtrar por el projecto tarda muchisimo mas.

Comment: Ok, igual no tiene nada que ver con tu problema, pero mi comentario apuntaba a que es innecesario hacer un MAX en este caso. Con respecto a la performance, lo que deberías verificar son los índices, debiera haber uno por Project y/u otro por DateBonePile, habría que ver los datos para ver cual aporta más a esta consulta. Y por último la pantalla que muestras es la del Mgt Studio que es lo que usas para conectarte, pero no te da información acerca del motor en sí, prueba con esta consulta: `SELECT @@VERSION`

Comment: Veo que estás haciendo una consulta al linked server. Qué tipo de dato tiene el `b.Project`? En mi experiencia, cuando hago consultas a la bd del ERP, a través de un linked Server, SQL Server hace una comparación entre `nvarchar` y `varchar`. Eso puede tomar DÉCADAS porque MSSQL hace la conversión por cada row. Intenta igualar el collation entre ambos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho ya grege mas detalles de los datos de la tabla asi como la version.

Comment: @Arriel ´´b.Project´´ es de tipo char. Deja inteno realizar el Collation.

Comment: Giovanni, intenta el collation. Si eso no ayuda, no desesperes. Lo que sí te puedo decir es que es muy probable que el problema sea la conversión entre el tipo de dato de la columna `b.project` y el string de sqlserver. Puedes intentar (aunque no es tan elegante) traer TODOS los registros del LinkedServer que cumplan el segundo where, los pones en una temp, y sobre eso aplicas el where del project.

Comment: @Arriel intente lo del collation y si redujo el tiempo, pero no tanto. no habia pensado en una temporal. deja lo hago y les digo como va

Comment: @Giovanni ¿si haces la consulta solo con la fecha sin incluir `b.Project = 'LUCENT FAD'` la consulta se realiza rápido?

Comment: @JosueArriola si. dura 10 segundos aprox

Comment: Entiendo, tal como te menciona @Arriel, la otra opción es ejecutar el query sin utilizar `b.Project = 'LUCENT FAD'` en el `where` y crear una tabla temporal, luego en la tabla temporal usar `where Project = 'LUCENT FAD'`.

Comment: @JosueArriola lo intentare y lo aplicare